# Parse Key-Value pair column stored as Varchar

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, key-value, varchar

I am attempting to query a column that has data stored in key-value pair. I thought it was JSON but after checking the properties it appears it's a `varchar` column. I am not quite sure how to query such a column. It looks something like:

```
{ "Employee":"John", "EmployeeID":"1", "Role":"Marketing" }
```

There are some nested pairs in there as well. Any help around how to extract values from this type of JSON looking column (it's of type `varchar`) will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it was a Redshift problem as it offers limited support to work with JSON files. I was able to query the key-value pair by using the following function: JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT()

```
Select *, 
json_extract_path_text(col, 'Employee', true) as Employee,
json_extract_path_text(col, 'EmployeeID', true) as EmployeeID,
json_extract_path_text(col, 'Role', true) as Role
from table;
```

Here's some documentation:

[https://sonra.io/redshift/working-with-json-in-redshift-options-limitations-and-alternatives/#:~:text=Redshift%20does%20not%20have%20a,SQL%20functions%20offered%20in%20Redshift](https://sonra.io/redshift/working-with-json-in-redshift-options-limitations-and-alternatives/#:%7E:text=Redshift%20does%20not%20have%20a,SQL%20functions%20offered%20in%20Redshift).
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/json-functions.html
[Querying JSON fields in Redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26612932/querying-json-fields-in-redshift)

Comment: You could cast this to a super data type.  There would be additional flexibility in working with the data then.